# Setting attributes to objects with pipes

Tags: r, attributes, pipe, rlang

I use attributes extensively I like to use pipes to set them up.

I use a lot `rlang::set_attrs`, but it was deprecated as of rlang 0.3.0.

However, there was no explanation of this deprecation (never mentioned on [NEWS.md](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/master/NEWS.md)), and the structure of this function seems really harmless to me:

```
> rlang::set_attrs
function (.x, ...) 
{
    warn_deprecated("`set_attrs()` is deprecated as of rlang 0.3.0")
    if (!is_copyable(.x)) {
        abort("`.x` is uncopyable: use `mut_attrs()` to change attributes in place")
    }
    set_attrs_impl(.x, ...)
}
<bytecode: 0x000001d759d6ecd8>
<environment: namespace:rlang>

> rlang:::set_attrs_impl
function (.x, ...) 
{
    attrs <- dots_list(...)
    if (identical(attrs, set_attrs_null)) {
        attributes(.x) <- NULL
    }
    else {
        attributes(.x) <- c(attributes(.x), attrs)
    }
    .x
}
<bytecode: 0x000001d75d8f2128>
<environment: namespace:rlang>
```

This seems to be the same thing as setting them in another line, with `attr()`.

I know about `data.table::setattr`, but it has not exactly the same behavior and seems less fit for piping.

In the end, should I avoid using `rlang::set_attrs`? If yes, what should I avoid reproducing in a custom function that would have the same purpose?

Comment: what about `magrittr::set_attr()` and `magrittr::set_attributes()`? I am not sure if they were there before their `rlang` counterparts (in which case that may have something to do with the deprecation), but for your use case they look like a good fit

Answer (score 2):

This answer may not be fulfulling for all, but it's some research (for perspective).

`set_attrs` was first soft-deprecated in Sept 2018, in
[a859be5](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/commit/a859be57c47ad841c93949de86ae4c946220df90). If you look at that commit, all of the uses of `set_attrs` were inline-replaced something like one of the below:

```diff
-  set_attrs(dict, class = class(x))
+  structure(dict, class = class(x))
```

or

```diff
-  x <- set_attrs(x, NULL)
-  x <- set_attrs(x, srcref = srcref)
+  attributes(x) <- NULL
+  x <- structure(x, srcref = srcref)
```

I think the `rlang` developers (perhaps even @lionel-henry who crafted that commit) will weigh in with rationale, but ... I suspect it was that the function wasn't adding a huge amount of convenience (very subjective, I admit).

---

While not awesome, one inline replacement could use `` `attr<-` ``:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  identical(rlang::set_attrs(mtcars, nm = "foo"))
# [1] FALSE

mtcars %>%
  `attr<-`(., "nm", "foo") %>%
  identical(rlang::set_attrs(mtcars, nm = "foo"))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @lionel-henry, do you have any insight on this topic? I don't mean to sound knowledgeable or authoritative on this.